# How do I find out what my time capsule is doing?

Tags: macos, time-capsule

I configured my Time Capsule so the LED blinks when it has activity.  As I type this I notice that it is blinking constantly, even though my network is idle.   The computer that uses it for backups (not the one I am on) is off, so it isn't running a backup.  The cable modem uplink to the ISP is not blinking -- so the traffic isn't from outside.

I looked into the logs and don't see much that is interesting.   Is there any way to find out what it is doing?

Answer (score 1):

From [Time Capsule 802.11n (4th Generation) - Setup Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/time_capsule_4th_gen_setup.pdf):

**If Your Time Capsule Status Light Flashes Amber**

[..]

For more information about why the light is flashing, open AirPort Utility, select your
Time Capsule, and then choose Manual Setup from the Base Station menu. Click Base
Station Status to display information about the flashing light.

You can also select “Monitor base station for problems” in AirPort preferences.
If the base station has a problem, AirPort Utility opens and walks you through
solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try capturing some network traffic in order to see what is going on using a tool such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) in order to do so. Try capturing data that has the source or destination IP of your Time Capsule. You'll need to make sure you're running your capture in *promiscuous* to ensure that you get traffic that isn't destined for your machine.